# Integration with respect to a parameter

Tags: integration

> Can anyone help me on how to evaluate the following integral using differentiation with respect to a parameter
>   $$
> \int_0^\infty e^{-(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})}dx
> $$
>   Any help would be greatly appreciated.
>   Thanks.

*From the comments:*

"I think I need to make it in the form of $\int_0^\infty e^{-u} du$ because I know the value of that integral."

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to start the problem but I think I need to make it in the form of /int_0^/infty e^{-u} du because I know the value of that integral

Comment: All you need to know is that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}$, then make some clever manipulations and substitutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{1}\exp\left(-\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)\,dx + \int_{1}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)\,dx $$
so:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{1}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\exp\left(-\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)\frac{dx}{x}\tag{1}$$
and by setting $y=x+\frac{1}{x}$, then $y=\sqrt{z}$, we get:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} I &=& \int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2-4}}e^{-(y^2-2)}\,dy = \frac{1}{2}\int_{4}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{z-4}}e^{-(z-2)}\,dz\\&=&\frac{1}{2e^2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}e^{-z}\,dz=\frac{1}{e^2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-w^2}\,dw\tag{2}=\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2e^2}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Thanks so much. Could you explain how you get equation one. I understand everything from there but I can't seem to figure out how you got to equation 1 from the above

Comment: @Andrew: in the second integral in the very first equation, replace $x$ with $\frac{1}{x}$.